# Java string as stream for reading

Tags: java

I have a Java string like `"10 20 3 0"`, now I would like to convert it into an array list. I know that in C++, the code should be like this:

```
string s = "10 20 3 0";
stringstream ss(s);
vector<int> arr;
string tmp;
while (ss >> tmp)
{
    arr.push_back(stoi(tmp));
}
```

How can I do this in Java, since I am quite new to java.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Java 8 , you can use streams. The following works

```
Stream<String> streamString = Stream.of(string.split(" "));
List<String> stringList = streamString.collect(Collectors.toList());
stringList.forEach(System.out::println);
```